# How to verify the structure of json?

Tags: json, python-3.x, schema

This is my data :

```
[{'DeviceInstanceId': 1, 'IsResetNeeded': False, 'ProductType': 'testing', 'Product': {'Family': '12345',"Model": "f10","Type": "data","Vendor": "qspi"}}]
```

I want to verify structure, type and keys are in same order like below or not, if not i should print missing data

```
'Product': {'Family': '12345',"Model": "f10","Type": "data","Vendor": "qspi"}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to have the keys and type in the same order. You can create a schema and try to read the JSON.

Comment: Yes..I need to verify that...Can u tell me how to create Schema

Comment: You can use https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for validating the JSON.

Comment: Can u tell me how i can create schema...I am new to this so...please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume this is your json converted to python dictionary

ordered_dict = [{'DeviceInstanceId': 1, 'IsResetNeeded': False, 'ProductType': 'testing', 'Product': {'Family': '12345',"Model": "f10","Type": "data","Vendor": "qspi"}}]

you can get all the keys in order using ordered_dict.keys(), now since it is a list of dictionary, you have to get keys of all items and compare it with each other to check if all keys are in order, i am converting to tuple of tuples to compare.

```
tuple_of_keys = tuple([tuple(j.keys()) for j in ordered_dict])
```

this will give you tuple of tuple of keys.

now do set of tuples like,

```
if len(set(tuple_of_keys)) == 1:
    print("all keys are in order")
else:
    print("missing data")
```

if length is equal to 1 then all keys are in the same order

to compare keys inside Product key, change code to

```
tuple_of_keys = tuple([tuple(j['Product'].keys()) for j in ordered_dict])
```

and follow same method again

if you want to pass order of keys manually and check if the order is matching then use below code.

```
order_of_keys = ('Vendor', 'Model', 'Type', 'Family')

ordered_dict = [{'DeviceInstanceId': 1, 'IsResetNeeded': False, 
'ProductType': 'testing', 'Product': {'Family': '12345',"Model": 
"f10","Type": "data","Vendor": "qspi"}},{'DeviceInstanceId': 1, 
'IsResetNeeded': False, 'ProductType': 'testing', 'Product': {'Family': 
'12345',"Model": "f10","Type": "data","Vendor": "qspi"}}]


def tests(order_of_keys,ordered_dict):
    tuple_of_keys = tuple([tuple(j['Product'].keys()) for j in ordered_dict])
    for each_item in tuple_of_keys:
        if each_item == order_of_keys:
            print("all keys are in order")
        else:
            print("missing data")
tests(order_of_keys,ordered_dict)
```

Comment: i have made changes to the above answer please check

Comment: when key order is changed the tuple items will not match and the set(tuple_of_keys) will not be equal to 1, why don't you change the order of keys and see if it works

Comment: Where can i pass my expected keys order...Commnted my function

Comment: please see above changes to the answer, use updated function and let me know thats what you are looking for

Comment: Can i get ur mail id?

Comment: can you share yours, i will reply to your mail